# How to check matching between dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement, dplyr

I have df:

```
A <- c("010410", "010420","010511","010519","010519","010591","010591",NA,NA)
B <- c("010392","010410","010420","010511","010512","010519","010592","010592","010593")
C <- c("010410", "010420", "010511", "010512", "010519", "010594", "010594", "010599",NA)
D <- c("010231", "010239", "010290", "010290", "010310", "010391", "010392", "010410", "010420")

df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

Now I want to find out in which columns match the following codes and return the dataframe where will be YES and NOW across A B C & D columns

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(c("010410","010420","010511","010512","010519","010290"))
```

- YES - if it matches
- NO- if such code does not exist in this column

Expected outcome:

```
         A      B       C       D
010410  YES    YES     YES     YES 
010420  YES    YES     YES     YES
010511  YES    YES     YES     NO
010512  NO     YES     YES     NO
010519  YES    YES     YES     NO
010290  NO      NO      NO     YES
```

Comment: All your leading zeros disappear because you don't quote each element. Does the leading zeros matter?

Comment: yes it matters.

Comment: So could you quote them? Otherwise all the leading zeros disappear and it will lead to wrong matches.

Comment: If your real data has leading 0s, please update `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and`df2` to have quotes so that your sample data has leading 0s.

Comment: see update.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way using TRUE and FALSE:

```
lapply(df, \(x) df2[[1]] %in% x) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  `row.names<-`(df2[[1]])
#            A     B     C     D
# 010410  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 010420  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 010511  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 010512 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 010519  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 010290 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If the Yes/Nos are strongly preferred, we can get them with this modification:

```
lapply(df, \(x) c("No", "Yes")[(df2[[1]] %in% x) + 1]) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  `row.names<-`(df2[[1]])
#          A   B   C   D
# 010410 Yes Yes Yes Yes
# 010420 Yes Yes Yes Yes
# 010511 Yes Yes Yes  No
# 010512  No Yes Yes  No
# 010519 Yes Yes Yes  No
# 010290  No  No  No Yes
```